# While loop use variable 2 times

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Hello guys I got a for loop cicle that prints me divs and information from SQL, I print the slider fields with the settings on the mysql like, Slider number, Field postion and so on, the problem is I have a Modal Bootstrap to be printed aswell but I cant print it inside the currently loop . 
My question is, is there anyway to store a  variable from a for cicle so it can be reutilized?

There is the code

```html
$ID=$row['ID'];
$sql = "SELECT NUM_Slides as valmax FROM slider_settings,Paginas, slider_config where slider_settings.ID = $ID and Paginas.ID= $ID and slider_config.ID=$ID";
$sqlconnect =$connect->query($sql);
$sqlresult =$sqlconnect->fetch_assoc();
for ($k = 1 ; $k <= $sqlresult['valmax']; $k++){ 
    echo "<div class='slider1'>";
    $sql1 = "SELECT P$k as campos, tituloP$k as titulo FROM slider_settings, Paginas,slider_config where slider_settings.ID = $ID and Paginas.ID= $ID and slider_config.ID = $ID";    
    $sqlconnect1 =$connect->query($sql1);
    $sqlresult1 =$sqlconnect1->fetch_assoc();
    
    echo "<div class='titulo'>
        <h2>$sqlresult1[titulo]</h2>
    </div>";
    
    for ($l = 1 ; $l <= $sqlresult1[campos]; $l++){ 
        $campo = "SELECT Butao,Titulo,Texto FROM slider_config, Paginas, slider_settings where slider_config.ID = $ID and Paginas.ID = $ID and slider_settings.ID =$ID and P_NUM = $k and Campo = $l";
        $sqlconnect2 = $connect->query($campo);
        $sqlresult2 = $sqlconnect2->fetch_assoc();

        echo "<div class='part' id='part".$l."'>
            <div id='imagem' class='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal".$l."'>
                <img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($sqlresult2['Butao']) . "'/>
            </div>
            <div id='titulo'>
                <h4>$sqlresult2[Titulo]</h4>
            </div>
            <div id='texto'>
                $sqlresult2[Texto]
            </div>
        </div>";
    } 
    echo "</div>";
}
```

and There is the code that cant printed inside of the div or modal wont display

```html
$modal = "SELECT Titulo_modal , Imagem_modal , Texto_modal FROM modal_settings , Paginas where modal_settings.ID = $ID and Paginas.ID= $ID and P_NUM_modal = $k and Campo_modal = $l";
$sqlconnect33 =$connect->query($modal);
$sqlresult33 =$sqlconnect33->fetch_assoc();
for ($n = 1 ; $n <= $sqlresult1[campos]; $n++){
    
    echo "<div class='modal fade' id='myModal".$n."'>
        <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <h4 class ='titulopopup'>$sqlresult33[Titulo_modal]</h4>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>
                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                    <div class='imagem'>
                        <img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($sqlresult33['Imagem_modal']) . "'/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='texto'>
                        $sqlresult33[Texto_modal]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
```

NOTE : the $ID is comming from another file :) and its work fine the first half of the code

Comment: Please, __unindent__ your code.

Comment: @u_mulder I did :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe create array like that

```
$array = [];
for ($n = 1 ; $n <= $sqlresult1[campos]; $n++) {
    $array[$k] = $i;
}
```

this way u can reuse your var stored in array in other for loop like

```
foreach ($array as $k => $i) {
    // and u get all your var :)
}
```

with your code u can do somethings like

```
$ID=$row['ID'];
// here
$array = [];
//
$sql = "SELECT NUM_Slides as valmax FROM slider_settings,Paginas, slider_config where slider_settings.ID = $ID and Paginas.ID= $ID
and slider_config.ID=$ID";
$sqlconnect =$connect->query($sql);
$sqlresult =$sqlconnect->fetch_assoc();
for ($k = 1 ; $k <= $sqlresult['valmax']; $k++){    
    echo "<div class='slider1'>";
        $sql1 = "SELECT P$k as campos, tituloP$k as titulo FROM slider_settings, Paginas,slider_config where slider_settings.ID = $ID and Paginas.ID= $ID and slider_config.ID = $ID";              
        $sqlconnect1 =$connect->query($sql1);
        $sqlresult1 =$sqlconnect1->fetch_assoc();
            echo "<div class='titulo'>
                <h2>$sqlresult1[titulo]</h2>
            </div>";
        for ($l = 1 ; $l <= $sqlresult1[campos]; $l++){ 
            // here
            $array[$k] = $l;
            $campo = "SELECT Butao,Titulo,Texto FROM slider_config, Paginas, slider_settings where slider_config.ID = $ID and Paginas.ID = $ID and slider_settings.ID =$ID and P_NUM = $k and Campo = $l";
            $sqlconnect2 = $connect->query($campo);
            $sqlresult2 = $sqlconnect2->fetch_assoc();

            echo "
            <div class='part' id='part".$l."'>
            <div id='imagem' class='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal".$l."'>
            <img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($sqlresult2['Butao']) . "'/>
            </div>
            <div id='titulo'>
                <h4>$sqlresult2[Titulo]</h4>
            </div>
            <div id='texto'>
                $sqlresult2[Texto]
            </div>
            </div>";
        }   
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: I need to push $k and $l at same time so I can use it on query to modals

Comment: so u can replace array_push() by $array[$k] = $i;

Comment: can u give me an example in code where do I define those arrays and where can I push them?

Comment: @RafaelSousa i edit my answer i hope this answer help u :)

Comment: where did u get $i ?

Comment: my bad is a $1 ? the next increments variable of u'r 2nd for loop, it's what u want?

Comment: I want to insert this